# Why is that given the same amount of sleep but waking up in different hours makes me rested/tired in the long term

Tags: sleep, rest

For context, I'm 17 so my recommended sleep amount should be 8-10 hours according to [Sleepfoundation](https://www.sleepfoundation.org/). I find myself rested more with about 9-10 hours.

So, I am a true believer in morning routines and this includes waking up early, so I tried to wake up early a few times (for "few times" I mean like 1 week then another 1 week) and I did it with obv having a morning routine, which mainly included a walk.
The problem is that even if I slept 9 hours (can't sleep more than that because I was waking up at 6, and having dinner with my family) after like a week and a half I felt really tired. So waking up wasn't about motivation or a schedule to follow, but just the fact that I wasn't rested enough for the day.

On the other side, now I sleep like 9.5 hours, waking up at 7:30 and I feel much more rested.

In both cases I use an alarm clock. How is that I'm more rested in the latter case than in the first? Also is there any scientific evidence?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I find that depending on the part of my sleep cycle that I wake up from I feel completely different. If I'm lightly sleeping, waking up is no issue, but if I'm in REM sleep, when I wake up I feel wrecked regardless of the actual amount of time I've slept. Maybe you're in particularly deep sleep around 6, but you're not so knocked out around 7:30.

Comment: @always_confused I get your point, but since I sleep the same amount of time, my sleep cycle should be roughly the same. Anddddd now that I checked I kinda wake up every time in the middle of my REM. Thanks a lot!! I'll try to schedule my night based on the cycles too, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how this fits into the context of fitness? Other than mentioning "includes a walk", there is nothing fitness related in this. We expect the questions on the site to have a fitness basis for being asked, and the main focus should revolve around the fitness aspect.

Comment: @JohnP I mentioned the tags "sleep" and "rest" and, above everything, sleep is the major player in getting the human body at rest in order to rebuild muscle well and efficiently. But, if I'm wrong, I'd really appreciate if you could link me to a relevant stack website.

Comment: @BenjaminCarafa - I understand, and there have been some questions on sleep, but this is somewhat an edge case. Also, there is no real good stack for these types of questions, which is why I didn't close it. I will be interested to see what the community says and if you get any good answers. Unfortunately, this is also highly personal. I avg between 6-8 and that's fine for me.

Comment: In the book Why We Sleep by Matthew Walker, the author does actually talk about this, that teenagers do indeed need more sleep, and also seem to do better getting up later than they do earlier. I can't remember the reasons, it's been a while since I read the book (and I doubt I'll get round to reading the whole thing again soon), but might be worth giving it a look.